# NullPointerException in Hashmap's get method

Tags: java

I have a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
 int qty = mSelectedBottles.get(bottleID);
```

I've checked that `mSelectedBottles` and `bottleID` are both NOT null.

`mSelectedBottles` is of type `Hashmap<Integer, Integer>` and `bottleID` is of type `int`

Comment: Post the full code. Otherwise its difficult to see

Comment: Posting the full exception would help in understanding your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because, Unboxing of a null value to primitive datatype. Here's enough code to recreate that `NullPointerException` yourself

```
int x;
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
x = map.get("hello");
```

**The auto-unboxing of the non-existent value was the issue.**

We know autoboxing was introduced to make coding easier, but it's a definite performance anti-pattern and can lead to annoying bugs like this which are non-intuitive.

Personally, I always try to remove autoboxing by making any such calls explicit, so that although the code is a  little uglier, it's also clearer what's happening.

You have to check `mSelectedBottles.get(bottleID)` is null or not before unboxing it to primitive int

From [Java Performance News Letter](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/news159.shtml)

Comment: It's always good to mention the source of your answer in case of copy paste: http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/news159.shtml